# execute one command in all open tabs in a terminal

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, terminal, gnome-terminal

I use a script which after execution opens different tabs and connects to different servers(using ssh). Now along with that,I want to run another command (say 'pwd').So how to do that?

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e 'ssh user@ip1' --tab -e 'ssh user@ip2'
```

This opens 2 tabs and connects to corresponding ip.After ssh in every tab I want to run another command, so that there will be two tabs,and after connecting to ip it will run specified command

Comment: Have you tried chaining commands like this `ssh user@ip2 && cmd && cmd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use SSH ability to execute remote command, like this:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e "ssh -A -t user@ipbridge \"ssh -t user@ip1 'pwd; /bin/bash -i'\""
```

Note the **/bin/bash -i** after the command. It is needed, because otherwise ssh will exit after the command.

Comment: it is working but after executing that command (after ssh) **"connection to user@ip1 closed "** is coming

Comment: and I don't want to disconnect from ip connection

Comment: @rohit264
Did you added `; /bin/bash -i` after the command? That should be enough to keep you logged in.

Comment: yes I added that. Basically I use ssh -A -t usr@ip ssh

Comment: "ssh -A -t user@ipbridge ssh -t user@ip 'pwd; /bin/bash -i'"  this is command..And after executing it , ssh is done for bridge ip & then goes to main ip and then executes pwd command.**And after that it is redirecting me to ipbridge**

Comment: @rohit264
You just need more quotes then. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) or any automation tool like any of these to do that you want. this tools allow execute a same command via ssh in multiple machines at same time in simple way.

using ansible you only need to do somthing like this

```
    ansible <your-list-of machine> -m shell -a "your command"
```

example

```
    ansible ip1 -m shell -a "echo $TERM"
```